# xrdp fails to work on Arch Linux using i3 window manager

Tags: linux, arch-linux, vnc, xrdp

I have a fresh Arch Linux installation,

```
[0s] $ uname -a
Linux fermata 4.8.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 27 09:26:14 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

on to which I've installed, enabled, and started xrdp:

```
systemctl --type="server"
...
xrdp-sesman.service     loaded active running xrdp session manager
xrdp.service            loaded active running xrdp daemon
```

I also have vncserver running on `:0`

```
[0s] $ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY # PROCESS ID
:0          615
```

Here are the ports that are being listened to:

```
[0s] $ sudo lsof -Pi | grep LISTEN
...
sshd       361 root    3u  IPv4  15595      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       361 root    4u  IPv6  15597      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
xrdp-sesm  370 root    7u  IPv4  15228      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:3350 (LISTEN)
xrdp       375 root    7u  IPv4  16056      0t0  TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
Xvnc       615 mark    4u  IPv4  14285      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
Xvnc       615 mark    5u  IPv6  14286      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
...
```

I'm trying to connect to the Arch box from macOS Sierra, so I downloaded and installed Microsoft Remote Desktop (Version 8.0.36 (Build 27228)) and created a profile that specifies the IP address of the Arch box, and has my Arch user account and password.

When I try to connect I get a grey box with the following messages:

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display 10
VNC started connecting
VNC connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
VNC error - problem connecting
```

I noted that the login was successful for `display 10`, and thinking that I needed to have VNC operating on :10 rather than :0, I killed the :0 session and stated a new on on :10. I get the same error as above with the line

```
...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display 11
...
```

Here is the output from the journal:

```
[0s] $ journalctl -f -u xrdp
-- Logs begin at Sat 2016-12-03 20:28:10 CST. --
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC Error after security negotiation
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC error before sending share flag
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC error before receiving server init
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC error before receiving pixel format
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC error before receiving name length
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC error before receiving name
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[DEBUG] VNC mod_exit
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: NULL:NULL - socket: 12
Dec 06 08:05:25 fermata XRDP[4451]: (4451)(139899817027328)[INFO ] An established connection closed to endpoint: 127.0.0.1:3350 - socket: 11
```

iptables is empty:

```
[3s] $ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Along the way I have added both a `.Xclient` and a `.xsession` file to my home directory, and tried `gnome-session` and `i3-session` in those files:

I also made a backup copy of `/etc/xrdp/startwm` and changed the original to have just

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-session
```

I've also tried `i3-session` and `xfce-session` here, those being the other environments installed.

When I tail `.vnc/fermata:10.log I see this:

```
** (nm-applet:4314): WARNING **: atk-bridge: GetRegisteredEvents returned message with unknown signature

** (nm-applet:4314): WARNING **: AT-SPI: Could not obtain desktop path or name


** (nm-applet:4314): WARNING **: AT-SPI: Could not obtain desktop path or name

polybars launched...
polybar|error  Monitor "HDMI2" not found or disconnected
polybar|error  Monitor "HDMI2" not found or disconnected
```

`polybar` is part of my i3 setup, so VNC at least is pointing to the session I ultimately want.

Obviously I'm missing some crucial piece between xrdp and VNC. I don't have any idea what that piece is.

Comment: I found this documentation, https://linux.die.net/man/5/sesman.ini, and in particular the `X11DisplayOffset` setting. The default is `10` to "prevent sesman from interfering with real X11 servers." This explains why the `xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display 10` message shows a `10`, and why the subsequent VNC line shows port `5910`. The `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` file shows it's trying `:10` as well: `[20161206-22:23:50] [INFO ] Xvnc start:Xvnc :10 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -rfbauth /home/mark/.vnc/sesman_mark_passwd -bs -ac -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96`

Comment: Running the command from the `xrdp-sesman.log` gets this result: `Xvnc TigerVNC 1.7.0 - built Sep  8 2016 19:36:24
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11804000, The X.Org Foundation


Tue Dec  6 22:34:08 2016
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5910
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0` Why is it connecting on screen 0?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pre-start a vnc session, xrdp does that for you (which is why it was starting :10 when you had :0 started, and when you had :10 started, it started on :11).

Window-manager typically goes in $HOME/.xsessionrc

The VNC session will exit when your .xsessionrc exits.. one thing you can do for a failsafe is try to run /usr/bin/xterm instead of a window manager.   This take all the complicatedness out of "Did my window manager run?".   If you get a screen with a single xterm, then you know you have the xrdp process working and are now working on a window manager issue.

Comment: I killed the :10 VNC session. I reverted the `/etc/xrdp/startwm` script back to its original state (which starts twm and xterm), and I moved `.xsession` to `.xsessionrc` and changed it's contents to be `xterm`. After restarting xrdp, I get the same error messages as before. So, it appears the issue is an xrdp/vnc issue and not a window manager issue.